# Как создать связь между типами данных nchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Только что начал учиться работе с базами данных, поэтому, пожалуйста, можно дать ответ более подробный или же хотя бы с ссылками на материалы.

Необходимо установить связь между таблицей с заказами и работниками (o_worker - w_surname, соответственно), чтобы в первой таблице отображалась фамилия сотрудника, который его выполнил. У o_worker и w_surname тип данных одинаковый (nchar(20)).

Однако при попытке создать связь между таблицами, выходит ошибка: [image: Ошибка при попытке создания связи]
[image: Схема]

Comment: Приложите схемы ващих таблиц, есть подозрение что вы все делаете не так.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Будет достаточно или еще что-то необходимо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка, как начинающего специалиста в том что вы связываете таблицы по заведомо не уникальным полям.
Ваша таблица заказов должна выглядеть так:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
(
    id_order INT,
    o_date DATETIME,
    o_name NVARCHAR(500),
    id_worker INT, -- (идентификатор работника)
    id_customer INT -- (идентификатор покупателя)
);
```

*Типы столбцов выбраны произвольно*

Почитайте про [нормальные формы](https://habr.com/ru/post/254773/) . Про то что такое констрейнты и [ключи](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15) .

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Сейчас обязательно попробую

Comment: @BrodeSt если мой ответ вам помог, проголосуйте за него и отметьте его как верный.